# selected dropdown from data json

Tags: jquery, json

**I've a code html :**

```html
<div id='dropdown' class='dropdown'>
  <select id='select_drop' class='select_drop'>
  <option value=''>-select-</option>
  <option value='1'>'<value>'</option>
  <option value='2'>'<value>'</option>
  <option value='3'>'<value>'</option>
  </select>
  </div>
```

**This is data json :**

```
{
    "bahan": [{
        "id_bahan": "4",
        "nm_jenis": "katun"
    }, {
        "id_bahan": "2",
        "nm_jenis": "spandex"
    }, {
        "id_bahan": "2",
        "nm_jenis": "spandex"
    }]
}
```

I want to fill value with data json, but I've `id_bahan` more than one.
I use `jquery`, and I add dropdown with `.clone()`

Comment: you want to put the value of `id_bahan` in the option?

Comment: i want to just selected option, but in html i only have one div#dropdown of select option. id_bahan more than one. so i want to show three div#dropdown with data id_bahan 4, 2, 2 in html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try a each loop

```
var obj = {
    "bahan": [{
        "id_bahan": "4",
        "nm_jenis": "katun"
    }, {
        "id_bahan": "2",
        "nm_jenis": "spandex"
    }, {
        "id_bahan": "2",
        "nm_jenis": "spandex"
    }]
};
$.each(obj.bahan,function(i,v){
   $('body').append('<select id="select_drop" class="select_drop"><option value="'+v.id_bahan+'">'+v.id_bahan+'</option></select>');
});
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but in html just show one div#dropdown. i've three id_bahan that show all in html

Comment: what exactly are you saying?

Comment: thanks for your answer, but in jsfiddle just show one div#dropdown. i've three id_bahan in json. i want to show three div#dropdown (<select><option></option></select>) like your jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id='dropdown' class='dropdown'>
  <select id='select_drop' class='select_drop'>
  <option value=''>-select-</option>
  </select>
  </div>
```

Write html part upto this later populate other options using jquery

```
$.each(data.bahan,function(e,i){
    $('#select_drop').append($('<option>', {'value': i.id_bahan,'text': i.nm_jenis}));
});
```